# ¿Cómo contar registros que coincidan de una variable de inicio de sesión?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql, php7

Tengo la siguiente tabla en mysql conectada a mi sistema en PHP.

```
 ID  |  PIN  |  respuesta1  |   respuesta2   |  respuesta3  |
  1    DD33         0                1               0
  2    DD33         1                3               1
  3    DD33         2                1               2
  4    EE42         2                1               2
```

Cómo puedo formular una consulta que cuente la cantidad de "pin" iguales usando la variable de sesión?

Mis variables de inicio de sesión es la siguiente:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $sesion = $_SESSION['username'];
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$cate = $_SESSION['cate'];
$rang = $_SESSION['rang'];
$pin = $_SESSION['pin']; -------------------Usaré esta
    if(!isset($sesion)){
        header("location: login.php");

    }else{

        echo "<center><h3> BIENVENIDA/O $sesion </h3></center><br>";
    }

    ?>
```

Una consulta similar cuenta la cantidad total de registros, pero yo quiero que cuente la cantidad de registros que existan con la variable que se inicia sesión (pin).

```
 $cuenta = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM 
 respuestas");
 $total = mysqli_num_rows($cuenta);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He resuelto mi problema, gracias:

```
 $cuenta = mysqli_query($conectar, "SELECT * FROM respuestas WHERE 
 pin = '".$_SESSION["pin"]."'");
 $total = mysqli_num_rows($cuenta);
```